# Levenshtein distance calculations

Tags: algorithms

What is the correct Levenshtein distance between the following strings?

```
hahaha
ahahah
```

These sites report different values:

http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/levenshtein/ (6)

http://planetcalc.com/1721/ (2)

The first site seems to be saying that you must compare each letter in place and change it to match the other string. (Full disclosure, I built the first site. I'm asking because someone emailed me telling me the calculation was incorrect.)

The second site (I think) is saying you can delete the first letter of either string, then add it to the end to get them to match.

Which is the correct algorithm? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrect. You are allowed to edit, add, or remove any char at a cost of one [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). You need to find the smallest value, so since (2)'s answer is smaller (and in fact, smallest) it is right.